# Read a video file from an URL and parse it using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

i have a large video file stored on a server. My task is to read that video file in chunks and then parse it into frames using OpenCV. 
i tried the below approach, but i am getting  "moov atom not found error"

```
import cv2

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/39f9fo9ch4gqoig/sample_video.mp4'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('window-name',frame)
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
    count = count + 1
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can someone suggest, how this can be achieved. I can't download the complete video file in my local system and read it due to space constraint. I don't want to put restriction of using only Youtube Videos. The source of video can be anywhere like HDFS, Google Drive etc. But I have a proper mechanism to read the video file in chunks from any source, just need help in processing those chunks using OpenCV.

Comment: Can you download the video file to your local machine and pass that path directly?

Comment: @ZdaR No that is not possible, as i already mentioned there is space constraint in my local system